# Does the surfaceview in android scale to whatever size it needs to be?

Tags: java, android

If I have a surface view and in that surface view I place a 50x50 image at the coordinates of 0 and 0 and then put that surface view inside of a relative layout and place it at the top left hand corner what will happen?

What will happen if I place that surface view at another position?
Also, since I am programming with a 480x800 device as my core emulator, what will happen if I used a device that is smaller?

Basically, how can I create something in a surface view and have the items in it increase or decrease in size proportionally to the device size?